# show all mysql colums in meganto modules shipping

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have add a shipping detail in **sales_shipment_track** table and in a pop up display data

popup

```
magento-abc/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/popup.html
```

only display title and number colums display but want to display all columns like description etc

i want to access all columns in this popup but i did not

with this function it get the data

```
$results = $block->getTrackingInfo();
```

but i did not get how and how can i add other table columns in this function